# can't find URLProtocol have wk_registerScheme

Tags: ios, xcode, protocols

In my project, have a `WKWebviewer`, I want to use `URLProtocol` to open a website, when open, I want to replace some images use local images, so I find `URLProtocol` Can do that, but Xcode show error message

> Type 'URLProtocol' has no member 'wk_registerScheme'

how to do that?

This is iPhone app, Xcode version is 10.2.1(10E1001)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    URLProtocol.wk_registerScheme("http")
    URLProtocol.wk_registerScheme("https")

    let url = URL(string:"https://www.google.com"); 
    let request = URLRequest(url:url!);
    //ViewWeb.loadRequest(request);

    webView.load(request);
}
```